# What are the files code.bat and code-cli.bat on VSCode Editor project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, visual-studio-code, electron

I am learning about the Microsoft project https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode, and I found these two files to run the application. The file and the documentation does not mention what does the files mean.

Doing a diff from them, this is their code difference:

[image]

What is the difference between code.bat and code-cli.bat on VSCode? When/why should I use one instead of the other?

While searching on their issue tracker I could find some mentions of them, but does not seem to explain the use of it:

1. [Output of code-cli.bat script not shown](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29049)
2. [Code doesn't interact well when started from cmd prompt](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30647)

---

## Update

It was closed an issue on the VSCode GitHub issue tracker, which the `--version` command line, does not works with the `code.bat`, but only with `code-cli.bat`:

1. [vscode$31363](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31363) Callling .\vscode\scripts\code.bat --version does not print the version

But they did not say nothing on why the we should use the `code-cli.bat` instead of the `code.bat` to the `--version` command line to work.

Comment: I think `cli` may give it away, **c**ommand-**l**ine **i**nterface.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But I still do not know what would be its differences from the `code.bat`. What would change on the application, perhaps on the console I am run these, when I start using the `code-cli.bat`, or vice-versa?

Comment: My assessment without reading the code is that one invokes commands in the Graphical User Interface and the other in the Command Line Interface.